# When I am applying filters, why sorting is not working on table?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, sorting, filter

I have a filters on the data and sorting on table header. When I am applying for filters, sorting stops working. Both are working separately but once filter applied sorting stops working.
Required assistance.

table-filter.pipe.ts

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({
  name: "tableFilter"
})

export class TableFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(list: any[], filters: any) {
    const keys = Object.keys(filters).filter(key => filters[key]);
    const filterUser = (user: { [x: string]: any; }) =>
      keys.every(key => {
        if (key == "sdob") {
          return new Date(user["dob"]) >= new Date(filters[key]);
        } else if (key == "edob") {
          return new Date(filters[key]) >= new Date(user["dob"]);
        } else {
          return user[key] === filters[key];
        }
      });
    return keys.length ? list.filter(filterUser) : list;
  }
}
```

app.component.ts

```
sort(property: any) {
    this.isDesc = !this.isDesc;
    this.column = property;
    let direction = this.isDesc ? 1 : -1;
    this.allUser.sort(function (a: { [x: string]: number; }, b: { [x: string]: number; }) {
      if (a[property] < b[property]) {
        return -1 * direction;        
      }
      else if (a[property] > b[property]) {
        return 1 * direction;
      }
      else {
        return 0;
      }
    });
  };
```

Live: https://angular-ivy-dubf37.stackblitz.io/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a problem of sync between your TS and the generated DOM.

In your `sort` function, you should pass the filtered users (*filteredUsers*), since the problem here is even after filtering (*DOM part*), it keeps sorting the whole users' list (*business logic part*) and that's not the intended behavior:

```
(click)="sort('first_name', filteredUsers)">First Name</th>
(click)="sort('last_name', filteredUsers)">Last Name</th>
```

And in the TS part become:

```
  sort(property: any, filteredUsers) {
    this.isDesc = !this.isDesc;
    this.column = property;
    let direction = this.isDesc ? 1 : -1;
    filteredUsers.sort(function(
      a: { [x: string]: number },
      b: { [x: string]: number }
    ) {
      if (a[property] < b[property]) {
        return -1 * direction;
      } else if (a[property] > b[property]) {
        return 1 * direction;
      } else {
        return 0;
      }
    });
  }
```

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-oe2pyn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**

Comment: can you help me with another issue? when I filtering my total record count is updating but how many applicable and how many not applicable is not updating. can you please look into that as well?

Comment: i have a getCounts function to calculate the count.